# Swagger 2 integration with Spring boot application

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

Getting error while integrating Swagger2 with spring boot application. I am stuck with this implementation. Any problem with the implementation or configuration?

Below are the configurations I have done to integrate Swagger2.

**SwaggerConfig.java**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api(){
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.regex("/api/.*"))
            .build()
            .apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfo(
            "My Project's REST API",
            "This is a description of your API.",
            "API TOS",
            "me@wherever.com",
            "API License",
            "API License URL", null
        );
        return apiInfo;
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

Added required dependencies of swagger2

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**application.properties**

```
server.port=10080
server.contextPath=/approot

------------------Hibernate Datasource configuration------------------
spring.datasource.url=${.service.jdbc.url}
spring.datasource.username=${service.jdbc.username}
spring.datasource.password=${service.jdbc.password}
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=${service.jdbc.driver}

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.show-sql: false

------------------Tomcat Access logs------------------
server.tomcat.accessLogEnabled=true
server.tomcat.accessLogPattern=%t responseTime=%D remoteHost=%h %l thread=%I %u method=%m uri=%U status=%s bytes=%b
server.tomcat.basedir=/var/log/tomcat-access

error.whitelabel.enabled=false
```

When I am trying to access the URL `http://localhost:10080/approot/swagger-ui.html`, I am getting below error and nothing displayed on the web page.

```
Aug 08, 2016 11:48:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcherServlet threw exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [error]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/approot/error] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.prepareForRendering(InternalResourceView.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:145)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1228)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:721)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:468)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:433)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:176)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Aug 08, 2016 11:48:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve custom
SEVERE: Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]
javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [error]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/approot/error] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.prepareForRendering(InternalResourceView.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:145)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1228)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:721)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:468)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:433)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:176)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You have an error but are not seeing the real error due to the way you have configured Spring's error handling. Post you web app config plus any stuff around error handling.

Comment: I have commented `error.whitelabel.enabled=false` in application.properties. Now there is no error at the backend. But I am getting the whitelabel error page.



Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Mon Aug 08 12:32:55 BST 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the solution to this problem. Swagger UI adds its own UI related modules to your jar file. There should not be any other `@EnableWebMvc` in your application if you want to see Swagger UI. I had this annotation on one of my `ExceptionHandler` because of which I was getting the error when trying to access Swagger UI.

Posted a blog on [integration of Swagger with spring boot application](http://swagger-spring-boot.blogspot.co.uk/).