# Swagger 2 (Spring fox) adds 'es' to my API's

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jax-rs, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I was just trying to integrate **Swagger** into my ***Spring Boot (JAX-RS)*** project built with Gradle.I was able to generate a docker (Swagger UI) for the same as following : 
[image: Swagger UI Docker]

I have configured my swagger with the default settings as follows :

```
package com.abc;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;

import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableMongoRepositories
@Slf4j
@Import({springfox.documentation.spring.data.rest.configuration.SpringDataRestConfiguration.class,springfox.bean.validators.configuration.BeanValidatorPluginsConfiguration.class})
@EnableSwagger2
public class ServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

    public static void run(String[] args) throws Exception{
        log.info("Started application on: 8080");
    }
}
```

As we can see in the image for ***GET*** **Events API** the docker shows /eventses .. So from where it has added **es** to /events API which is written as :

```
@GET
public HashMap<String, Object> getEventList(@DefaultValue("1") @QueryParam("page") int page,
        @DefaultValue("10") @QueryParam("rpp") int rpp, @QueryParam("events") String eventIds) {
    HashMap<String, Object> eventsResultMap= new HashMap<String, Object>();

    List<Events> events = null;

    if (eventIds != null && eventIds.length() > 0) {
        List<String> eventsIdList = Arrays.asList(eventIds.split(","));
        log.info("" + eventsIdList);
        events = eventService.getEvents(eventsIdList);
    } else {
        events = eventService.getEvents(page - 1, rpp);
    }
    eventsResultMap.put("EVENTS", events);

    HashMap<String, Object> recordsMetaMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    recordsMetaMap.put("total", eventService.totalCount());
    recordsMetaMap.put("page", page);
    recordsMetaMap.put("rpp", rpp);
    eventsResultMap.put("_metadata", recordsMetaMap);
    log.info("The events you have queried for are:" + eventsResultMap);
    return eventsResultMap;
}
```

Please, guide me where I am doing wrong.What custom configs need to be done.

I have taken [Reference](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#getting-started) from spring official  documentation.

Comment: i dont think it is reading the method properly. For example it is written as `@GET`, but in pic its showing as `POST` and others types. Just a thought....and i think the `es` is due to the return type of `HashMap`. Have you tried using `@ApiOperation` annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a jax-rs implementation with spring boot, you should use swagger-core jax-rs libraries rather than spring fox. Swagger team has provided very detailed instructions [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-JAX-RS-Project-Setup-1.5.X) on how to configure your application for different implementations like jersey, rest-easy etc. I found it very easy to integrate for jersey 2.x.

To make your swagger documentation rich, you should try to provide as much meta data as you can using different swagger annotations as documented [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations-1.5.X). Swagger makes great use of these annotations combined with jax-rs annotations in some cases (E.g. QueryParam vs PathParam identification).

If you let me know which jax-rs implementation you are using, I might be able to provide you some sample configuration.

**Edit:**

For Jersey 2.x you will need to add something like this in your Jersey Configuration class (which extends `org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig`):

```
@Bean
public BeanConfig swaggerConfig() {

    register(ApiListingResource.class);
    register(SwaggerSerializers.class);

    BeanConfig config = new BeanConfig();
    config.setConfigId("your-config-id");
    config.setTitle( "Your Title" );
    config.setSchemes(new String[] { "https", "http" });
    config.setBasePath("your application base path E.g. /api");
    config.setResourcePackage("package to be scanned E.g. com.example");
    config.setPrettyPrint(true);
    config.setScan(true);
    return config;
}
```

Other than that, you will need to annotate your endpoint(service) classes with swagger annotations. E.g.

```
@Path("/material")
@Service
@Api(value = "Material")
public class MaterialEndpoint {

    @POST
    @ApiOperation(value = "Create Material")
    @ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = 201, message = "Success", response = CreateMaterialResponse.class),
                            @ApiResponse(code = 409, message = "Failure", response = ErrorResponse.class) })
    public Response createMaterial(CreateMaterialRequest createMaterialRequest){
// Code goes here
   }

}
```

And your entities with swagger annotations. It is upto you how rich you want your swagger documentation to be. Depending on that you can choose to annotate more or less classes.

Comment: This doc https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-Jersey-2.X-Project-Setup-1.5 is about maven project.. How about Gradle ?

Comment: I believe, as long as you are providing the correct locations (MavenCentral()) in your repositories section and providing the dependency in gradle way, the configuration should work.

Comment: I am using Jersey 2.X

Comment: Ok lemme check this in evening and will let you know...Thanks for your precious efforts bro...

Comment: Have you removed spring fox configuration? Specifically this:

`@Import({springfox.documentation.spring.data.rest.configuration.SpringDataRestConfiguration.class,springfox.bean.validators.configuration.BeanValidatorPluginsConfiguration.class})`
`@EnableSwagger2`

and any spring fox dependency because spring boot might be initalizing them because of their presence in classpath

Comment: Its not working but I am still accepting your's answer Since my bounty will get wasted and you really made many efforts to make it work,but unfortunately it didn't

Comment: Thanks for that. But can you upload a sample project of yours on github or something? I have swagger working with jersey 2.x smoothly. I am really curious to find out why its not working for you. I am pretty sure it is some small miss.

Comment: I am using Bitbucket for it...Kindly give me your email so that I could add you there since the project is Private..

Comment: have you found any problem in that?

Comment: I got the code but didnt get a chance to look at it yet.

Comment: sure...Lemme know if you get any clue :)

Answer (score 3):

Everything in **`/eventses`** comes from Springfox's support for Spring Data REST and has nothing to do with the `getEventList` method in your controller. If you don't want to have auto-discovery of your entities like that, removing the class from the `@Import` line should do the trick.

Comment: Yeah I have already tried this trick before I asked this question..Sorry  I didn't mentioned this to my question..But the problem is If I remove the Line @Import, Then all my controllers gets vanishes fro  swagger UI (Which are now visible), could you tell me how could I make my controllers Scannable ?

Comment: Indeed, you need to tell Swagger about your controllers. Do you have a [docket](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#configuring-springfox) in your project? You can take a very good example for a `SwaggerConfig` class from [this linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38827281/3990817).

I usually restrict the discovery of controllers via the `RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage` predicate, but you can indeed start with `.any()` and verify that your controllers get picked up.

Comment: I will try this and will let you know...and also will accept your ans (If it worked)